# Flash using one sound channel to play through an array of sounds

Tags: flash, audio

I Am wondering if is possible to use one sound channel to play through an array of sounds? Perhaps by using a complete event or other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, just change the sound var by any means, and assign it again to soundchannel, play, etc...